# GoLang: Allocating Slice of Slices in functions results in index out of range

Tags: go, slice

I've been trying some things out in Go and I've hit a problem that I can't figure out.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func writeHello(i int, ) {
        fmt.Printf("hello, world "+strconv.Itoa(i)+"\n")
}

type SliceStruct struct {
    data [][]int;
}

func (s SliceStruct) New() {
    s.data=make([][]int,10);
}

func (s SliceStruct) AllocateSlice(i int) {
    s.data[i]=make([]int,10);
}

func (s SliceStruct) setData(i int, j int, data int) {
    s.data[i][j] = data;
}

func (s SliceStruct) getData(i int, j int) int {
    return s.data[i][j]
}

func useSliceStruct(){
    sliceStruct := SliceStruct{};
    sliceStruct.New();
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        sliceStruct.AllocateSlice(i);
        for j:=0; j<10; j++ {
             sliceStruct.setData(i,j,i);
            writeHello(sliceStruct.getData(i,j));
        }
    }
}

func dontUseSliceStruct(){
    data:=make([][]int,10);
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        data[i]=make([]int,10);
        for j:=0; j<10; j++ {
            data[i][j] = i;
            writeHello(data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    dontUseSliceStruct();
    useSliceStruct();
}
```

When it gets to the function useSliceStruct, the code fails at the first call to AllocateSlice() with an index out of range error.

As far as I can tell the code for the two methods does idential things. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOH, just worked it out.

I wasn't using a reference to the struct in the function declarations.

```
func (s SliceStruct)
```

Should have been

```
func (s *SliceStruct)
```